# Error: Unable to find column position by name

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring, swagger

**Hay un error en la consola al momento de realizar consulta para traer todos los estudiantes de la base de datos.
El error es el siguiente**

```
  "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to find column position by name: idgrupo; SQL [n/a]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232)\r\n\tat
```

**Los siguientes codigos son las Clases que hacen uso de "idgrupo"**

**Clase Asignatura, son las materias que un estudiante veria en su grupo**

```
package com.natalia.gestionnotas.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name = "asignatura")
public class Asignatura implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idasignatura")
    private int idasignatura;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "asignatura_grupo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idasignatura", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idgrupo", nullable = false)
    )
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Grupo> grupos;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "asignatura")
    private List<Nota> notas;

    public void agregarGrupo(Grupo grupo) {
        if (this.grupos == null) {
            this.grupos = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        this.grupos.add(grupo);
    }

    public void removerGrupo(Grupo grupo) {
        this.grupos.remove(grupo);
        grupo.getAsignaturas().remove(this);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     **/
   

    /**
     * Getter y Setter
     **/
```

** Clase Estudiante, la cual hereda de Usuario y el cual contiene nombre, contraseña, rol**

```
package com.natalia.gestionnotas.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;

    
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idusuario")
public class Estudiante extends Usuario {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idgrupo")
    private Grupo grupo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estudiante")
    private List<Nota> notas;

    /** Getter y Setter **/
```

** Clase Curso, es la clase que contiene la lista de estudiantes**

```
package com.natalia.gestionnotas.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

  
@Entity
@Table(name = "grupo")
public class Grupo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idgrupo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String numenclatura;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idprofesor")
    private Profesor profesor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "grupo")
    private List<Estudiante> estudiantes;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "grupos")
    private List<Asignatura> asignaturas;

    /**
     * Constructor
     **/
    

    /**
     * Setter y getter
     **/
```

Query que genera el error

```
    @Query(value = "select * from usuario", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Estudiante> filtrar();
```

La idea es básica, hacer una web con Angular para ingresar como docente y gestionar las notas de los estudiantes.

Comment: Donde están las querys SQL?

Comment: Eliminé la etiqueta [tag:sql] porque parece no tener relación, leer la descripción de la etiqueta. Si después de leer la descripción de la misma consideras que estoy equivocado, agrega de nuevo la etiqueta, pero considera agregar o cambiar la redacción de la pregunta lo que tiene que ver con la misma. Un saludo.